# Minimum number of swaps to sort a list of triangles

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Let `L = list  of S's` where `S = list of lengths of sides of a triangle`.

Then, I need to find the minimum number of swaps required to sort the list L.

The list L is said to be sorted:

1. if the elements within each S list are sorted in non-decreasing order and
2. if the elements at ith index of each S list are sorted in non-decreasing order.

where `0 <= i <= 2`

**Note:** Two types of swap operations can be done :

- Either elements withing a S list can be swapped (requires 1 swap)
- Two complete S lists can be swapped without changing the order of elements.
     (requires 3 swaps)

Any efficient algorithm in terms of Time Complexity to find the minimum number of swaps required to sort the list L **whenever possible**?

**EDIT:**

As pointed out correctly by @Mbo, it is not always possible to sort such a list L. So, it would be great if someone provides an algorithm to **check if the list L can be sorted followed by sorting if possible.**

Comment: It seems that 1) and 2) conditions are similar. Would you specify better?

Comment: @MBo In 1) I am talking about elements within a Sj list for S1, S2,...
Suppose, if S1 = [a, b, c], then a,b,c should be in non-decr order.
In 2) I am talking about corresponding elements of each Sj list such as S1[0], S2[0], S3[0]... should be sorted in non-decreasing order.

Comment: It is impossible in general case. Consider (4,7,10) and (5,6,7)

Comment: So, you are basically looking for an algorithm to sort an 3xN matrix such that all the rows and all the columns are non-decreasing? As pointed out by MBo, I don't think this is always possible.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Please see my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood, but it seems to me that you have to sort the 3 elements in each S. Once this is done, it is simply a matter of sorting the triplets in order of the list {S0[0],S1[0]...} and then checking whether the sequences {S0[1], S1[1].....}, {S0[2], S1[2]..} are in increasing order. If you have n triangles the asymptotic worst case complexity would be O(n)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He's not asking how to do the sorting, but rather to compute the minimum number of swaps required given a particular arrangement of triangles. So how many swaps will it take to sort the individual triangles' sides, and then how many swaps will it take to sort the list of triangles. That is, the *theoretical minimum* number of swaps that the perfect sorting algorithm would make.